# Neatest way to redirect urls without trailing slash in HAproxy

Tags: redirect, haproxy

What is the neatest way to redirect these

http://example.com/test to http://example.com/test/

(It should work no matter what "test" is).  I'm new to HAProxy - I have different apache backends.  Have it working for URLs of this format http://example.com/test/ but cannot get the other type to work.
Have tried:
(1)

```
http-request set-path %[path]/ unless { path_end / }
```

which doesn't load the html page properly - possibly because it's screwing up e.g. the referenced JS files.
(2)

```
http-request redirect code 301 prefix / drop-query append-slash if missing_slash
```

from the documentation.  I figure I need some kind of slight adjustment to this but don't know where to start with it.  Any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This would potentially best be done at the back-end, since only the back-end has a way to actually know which paths should be redirected.  But, it should be possible from HAProxy.

> It should work no matter what "test" is

I am skeptical that this is precisely what you need, because then (e.g.) `/css/common.css` becomes `/css/common.css/`, which would be wrong.

I'm inclined to think you want something like this:

```
http-request redirect code 301 prefix / drop-query append-slash if { path_reg /[^/\.]+$ }
```

Redirect to the same path, with the query removed and `/` appended to the end, if the path ends with a `/` followed by at least 1 (or more) characters that is neither `/` nor `.`.

This should redirect `/test` to `/test/` and `/hello/world` to `/hello/world/` but it should leave paths like `/js/example.js` and `/images/cat.png` and `/favicon.ico` unaffected.

Deeper nesting should work correctly, too, because regular expressions like this either find a match or don't, and this expression only considers whatever is after the final slash in the path.  If it contains a dot or nothing, then there is no match, which seems correct.